# Move windows between screens in dual screen mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, window-manager

I have a laptop and a 27 inch monitor. I have Qt running on one monitor and Pycharm on the other. Is there a way to make a key combination to swap all the windows between both screens. The reason is that I want to program on the big screen only. I have already 4 workspaces and all of them are already used.

The output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.2*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1366x768       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Both are 1920x1080, for the workspaces, I don't want to be switching a lot and I don't need more than 4x2screens for now. Being able to swap both screen contents would save me the bending to come closer to the small laptop screen (using an external keyboard, I can't have the laptop screen as close to me as the big screen du to the laptop's shape)

Comment: The external screen is extending the laptop on the left side (main screen is shown on the external screen)

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just need to precise that my workspaces are in Compiz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Script to swap all windows from screen 1 --> screen 2 and vice versa

The script assumes the screens are of the same *vertical* resolution, and the left screen is the primary one. The *horizontal* resolutions of both screens is searched by the script.

#### How to set up

The script needs `wmctrl` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `swap_windows` (no extension) in `~/.bin`. Create the directory if it doesn't exist already, and *make the script executable*.
2. If you just created the directory `~/bin` (it didn't exist yet), either log out/in or run in a terminal: `source ~/.profile`.
3. test run the script with the command:

   ```
   swap_windows
   ```
4. If all works as expected, add shortut key; choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",  cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def get_shiftright(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def get_shiftleft(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if  "+0" in l and not "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return -int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def swap_windows():
    xr_output = get("xrandr")
    shift_r = get_shiftright(xr_output)
    shift_l = get_shiftleft(xr_output)
    w_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines()]
    for w in w_data:
        props = get("xprop -id "+w[0])
        if any(["_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props]):    
            if 0 < int(w[2]) < shift_r:
                shift = shift_r
            elif shift_r-shift_l > int(w[2]) >= shift_r:
                shift = -shift_r
            else:
                shift = 0
            command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), str(int(w[3])-28), w[4], w[5]])
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])     
swap_windows()
```

---

### 2. Script to move (all) windows from one monitor to the other

The script below moves windows in a dual monitor setup from one screen to another, either:

- from the left to the right monitor -->

  or
- from the right to the left monitor <--

Depending on the argument you run it with (`left` or `right`)

The script (again) assumes the screens are of the same *vertical* resolution, and the left screen is the primary one. The *horizontal* resolutions of both screens is searched by the script.

#### How to set up

The script needs `wmctrl` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `shift_windows` (no extension) in `~/.bin`. Create the directory if it doesn't exist already, and *make the script executable*.
2. If you just created the directory `~/bin` (it didn't exist yet), either log out/in or run in a terminal: `source ~/.profile`.
3. test run the script with the commands

   ```
   shift_windows right
   ```

   and:
       shift_windows left

   In the first case, windows on your *left* screen should move to the right screen and in the second case vice versa.
4. If all works as expected, add the script to two shortcut combinations: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the commands as explained above.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

vec = sys.argv[1]

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",  cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def get_shiftright(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def get_shiftleft(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if  "+0" in l and not "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return -int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def shift_windows():
    xr_output = get("xrandr")
    shift_r = get_shiftright(xr_output)
    shift_l = get_shiftleft(xr_output)
    w_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines()]
    for w in w_data:
        props = get("xprop -id "+w[0])
        if vec == "right":
            check = (0 < int(w[2]) < shift_r, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True)
            shift = shift_r
        if vec == "left":
            check = (shift_r-shift_l > int(w[2]) >= shift_r , "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True)
            shift = -shift_r
        if check == 2:
            command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), str(int(w[3])-28), w[4], w[5]])
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
shift_windows()
```

---

### 3. Move a single window from one screen to another

Although not literally your question, with just a few lines more, you can either move *all* windows from one screen to the other, but also a single one (the frontmost) with a key combination.

With the script below, you can move *all* windows with the command:

```
shift_windows right
```

or move a single window with the command:

```
shift_windows right s
```

The setup is pretty much the same as the script above (don't forget to install `wmctrl`)

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

vec = sys.argv[1]
try:
    n = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    n = "a"

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c",  cmd]).decode("utf-8")

def get_shiftright(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def get_shiftleft(xr_output):
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if  "+0" in l and not "+0+0" in l][0].split()
    return -int([it for it in lines if "x" in it][0].split("x")[0])

def shift_windows():
    xr_output = get("xrandr")
    shift_r = get_shiftright(xr_output)
    shift_l = get_shiftleft(xr_output)
    w_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines()]
    if n == "s":
        frontmost = [l for l in get("xprop -root").splitlines() if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" in l][0].split()[-1]
        frontmost = frontmost[:2]+"0"+frontmost[2:]
        w_data = [l for l in w_data if frontmost in l]
    for w in w_data:
        props = get("xprop -id "+w[0])
        if vec == "right":
            check = (0 < int(w[2]) < shift_r, "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True)
            shift = shift_r
        if vec == "left":
            check = (shift_r-shift_l > int(w[2]) >= shift_r , "_TYPE_NORMAL" in props, "TYPE_DIALOG" in props).count(True)
            shift = -shift_r
        if check == 2:
            command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), str(int(w[3])-28), w[4], w[5]])
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
shift_windows()
```

Comment: I tried both scripts but I always get an error about out of range   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./shift_windows", line 34, in <module>
    shift_windows()
  File "./shift_windows", line 20, in shift_windows
    shift_r = get_shiftright(xr_output)
  File "./shift_windows", line 11, in get_shiftright
    lines = [l for l in xr_output.splitlines() if " connected primary" in l][0].split()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It is actually connected

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems that it works fine. But back to my question, is it possible to swap both screens? moving left to right and right to left at the same time?

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shift' referenced before assignment

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./shift_windows", line 30, in <module>
    swap_windows()
  File "./shift_windows", line 28, in swap_windows
    command = "wmctrl -ir "+w[0]+" -e 0,"+(",").join([str(int(w[2])+shift), w[3], w[4], w[5]])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shift' referenced before assignment

Comment: Yes I will clean up the comments afterwards. It seems to work on a workspace except that the windows tend to shift towards the bottom of the screen when I do it many times. Thanks a lot ! But when I switch back to other workspaces(In compiz) the windows are weird or sometimes even minimized or moved to a random place.

Comment: @Mehdi fixed the deviation :)

Comment: `wmctrl` is buggy and impossible to relay on. What is the magic number "28"? On my machine (Ubuntu 18.10) `wmctrl -lG` shows double of the actual x-offset (E.g., 3840 instead of 1920). The y-offset is also inconsistent.
The problem is not with your script, but with this utility.

Comment: You definitely need to make the script executable `chmod +x ~/bin/swap_windows` that would be worth mentioning in the answer. Otherwise it somewhat works partially - some windows were swapped, some were not.

Comment: btw: if you have custom icon splitting on task bar, you may need to find a way how to refresh that - I was able to do that by alt-tabing to target windows and moving them manually back and forth