# How can I disable 'focus follows mouse' when the Super key is pressed

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, dconf, xbindkeys

...and enable it on keyup event?

The problem is, when using the keyboard to move windows across multiple monitors, focus is stolen by the mouse once the focused window I'm moving is moved away from the cursor.  Then I have to put the cursor back on the window I'm moving to give it focus.

Comment: so essentially , what you're asking is that you want the cursor to move with the window ?

Comment: See my answer to this post. http://askubuntu.com/q/804211/295286  It basically creates a shortcut to move/jump  focused window to different monitor(without loosing focus) . If you wish, i can modify it so that it also brings mouse pointer with it.

Comment: @Serg Yes, that would actually be better.  I'll have to give your script a try.

Comment: @serg I ended up reducing the 'prevent focus stealing' in Compiz, which helps when moving windows via shortcuts.  What it doesn't do is prevent focus stealing when resizing windows to quadrants of the monitor with shortcuts.  Any thoughts on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

enter Compiz Manager...search for the menu below "General" dont know the name in english...on it, you should see "Show Mouse" unselect it, and its done. But if you want to keep this config, just enter clicking on the icon and change the key to activate.

Hope it helps

Ed1

Well...the compiz manager installed on your computer is basic...so you need to install plugins for compiz..

sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra

sudo apt-get update

exit

And then restart your machine...now should appear the menu with the show mouse option.

Comment: There's no 'enable/disable when super key is pressed' option.  That's the trick, I need a way to toggle 'focus follows mouse' tied to the super key.

Comment: oops...sorry...then you need to install plugins for Compiz....i will edit my answer with the Terminal commands you need

Comment: I already had all the compiz plugins installed.  I'm not looking to reveal the mouse location, but to disable the mouse when the Super key is pressed. Or per @Serg's suggestion, make the mouse follow the active window.