# Two monitors - move windows to the second with a shortcut?

Tags: gnome, window

I would like to move windows between two monitors with a shortcut. 
I am using "move to second workspace" bu the second wortkspace is appearing on my first monitor as well.

I found some solutions for KDE but I am very happy with gnome at the moment. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create keyboard shortcuts to move windows without Compiz](http://askubuntu.com/questions/804211/create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-move-windows-without-compiz)

Comment: See the solution provided, test it out. If it works, good. If.necessary i can edit it to suit your particular needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap windows between screens in dual screen mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597884/swap-windows-between-screens-in-dual-screen-mode)